# How to make user input not case sensitive in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a program that asks for user input and checks if it is correct, however it is case sensitive so it would be great if you could explain to me how to make incase sensitive in Ruby,

Thanks!

Comment: What is the condition you are checking the input against? How are you doing it?

Comment: Your wording "it is case sensitive" is ambiguous. Is the condition supposed to be case sensitive, or is your code unexpectedly working case sensitively?  Although the reader might manage to disambiguate it from the following part, you should not put burden on the reader.

Comment: Data is data. When you *use* (ie. 'check') the input, do so in a case-insensitive manner. (Alternatively the input case can be normalized; but that loses information.)

Comment: I used a unless statement that said to say "nope" if the input did not equal to "Ronald" with the capital letter, so when it asks for the input and I write "ronald" it will say "nope"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you mean by "case insensitive" is that even if the user types a capital letter, the letter printed back to the user will always be lowercase.

I'm not sure if the actual *input entry* can be made automatically lowercase.

However, if you'd like to simply convert all characters in the input string to their lowercase equivalents, you can:

```
 puts "Type some capital letters - I dare you..."
 input = gets
 puts input.downcase
```

of course, the real answer is simply `capitalString.downcase`.